# Rotate xy points using multiple angles - python

Tags: python, pandas, rotation, complex-numbers

I'm currently rotating xy points using the angle between a reference point and a single fixed point. I'm hoping to include two fixed points to rotate the points. I'm just not sure how this can be achieved.

Using below, the points that get rotated are displayed in `x` and `y`. The angle between `X_Ref`, `Y_Ref` and `X_Fixed`,`Y_Fixed` is used to rotate the points (displayed as the black vector in the initial distribution figure).

The current process is to transform the fixed/ref points to complex numbers to compute the rotation. I finally re-center the rotated points so `X_Ref`, `Y_Ref` is centred at 0,0 (shown in the after rotation figure).

**However, I'm hoping to include the angle between `X_Ref`, `Y_Ref` and `X2_Fixed`,`Y2_Fixed`. The second figure below shows how only one angle is accounted for when rotating the points. I'm hoping to account for both to return the intended out. Any suggestions/advice is welcome.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Period' : ['1','1','1','1'],        
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','D'],                             
    'x' : [0.0,-1.0,3.0,2.0],
    'y' : [0.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0],     
    'X_Ref' : [1,1,1,1],
    'Y_Ref' : [1,1,1,1],        
    'X_Fixed' : [-2,-2,-2,-2],
    'Y_Fixed' : [-2,-2,-2,-2],      
    'X2_Fixed' : [4,4,4,4],
    'Y2_Fixed' : [-2,-2,-2,-2],           
    })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))
ax.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax.set_ylim(-5,5)
ax.grid(False)
```

Initial distribution:

[image]

```
#transform fixed/ref points to complex numbers
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df[f] = df['X_'+f] + 1j*df['Y_'+f]
    df.drop(['X_'+f, 'Y_'+f], axis=1, inplace=True)

#compute the rotation  
df['angle'] = - np.angle(df['Ref'] - df['Fixed'])

#compute the rotation for every point 
df['rotated'] = (df['x'] + 1j*df["y"]) * np.exp(1j*df['angle'])
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df[f+'_Rotated'] = df[f] * np.exp(1j*df['angle'])

#center the dataset around the "reference" point 
df['translation'] = - df['Ref_Rotated']
df['NewPoint'] = df['rotated'] + df['translation']
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df[f+'_Transformed'] = df[f+'_Rotated'] + df['translation']

#revert to cartesian coordinates
df['x2'] = np.real(df['NewPoint'])
df['y2'] = np.imag(df['NewPoint'])
for f in ['Ref', 'Fixed']:
    df['NewX_'+f] = np.real(df[f+'_Transformed'])
    df['NewY_'+f] = np.imag(df[f+'_Transformed'])
```

After Rotation:

```
output = df[['Label', 'x2', 'y2', 'NewX_Ref', 'NewY_Ref', 'NewX_Fixed', 'NewY_Fixed']]

ax.scatter(output['NewX_Ref'], output['NewY_Ref'], marker = 'x', zorder = 5, color = 'black')
ax.scatter(output['NewX_Fixed'], output['NewY_Fixed'], marker = '+', zorder = 5, color = 'red')
ax.scatter(output['x2'], output['y2'], marker = 'o')
```

[image]

Intended rotation:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't matrix transformations be helpful here?

Comment: I'm confused -- you have vectors at a 90-degree angle.  You want to rotate the entire figure, and end up with opposite vectors?  Exactly how does that make sense in your system?

Comment: Please note that your code is not minimal: there is a large amount of graphing overhead that is mere visualization, not related to the problem.  Please replace it with a simple output, such as the direction of each vector.

Comment: How does this work, that your common point moves from (1, 1) to (0, 0)?  This is not a simple rotation.

Comment: @Prune, I understand the intended output is not a simple rotation. The reference point should be at 0,0 after rotation. I have re-phrased the structure of the question. I'll add more detail to the figures.

Comment: Please explain independently what you are trying to do; very few people are going to trouble to reverse-engineer your intent from you code.  You have a "fixed" vector that is not fixed.  You say that you're using the angle between them to rotate the vectors, but you say nothing about the rotation algorithm.
Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Defining an angle between 2 points does not make much sense. An angle can only be defined between 2 vectors, or 3 points. In polar coordinates, an angle can be expressed for a single point, but this angle is implicitly understood to be with respect to a reference direction (often the x-axis) and a reference point (the origin).
According to `- np.angle(df['Ref'] - df['Fixed'])`, you actually consider `Ref` and `Fixed` as vectors and thus compute the angle of the vector `Ref` - `Fixed` (with respect to the x-axis and the origin and with clockwise orientation). I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: `using the angle between a reference point and a single fixed point` This makes no sense, there is no angle between two points. Maybe hand sketch the angles which you are trying to describe into the images? No one here seems to understand which angles you are talking about..

Answer (score 3):

The problem to be solved is not clear. From what I understand the problem is to make a point rotate around a pivot point with a certain angle theta. The dataframes of pandas are not very suited to the problem, let's use numpy instead. For convenience we first define a class to represent points and vectors in the plane.

```py
class Coord:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
        assert x.shape == y.shape
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.shape = x.shape

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return np.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Coord(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Coord(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Coord({self.x}, {self.y})"
```

For instance `Coord(2, 3)` simply represents a point or a vector with coordinates (2, 3). Additions and subtractions can be performed: `Coord(2, 3) + Coord(1, -2)` returns `Coord(3, 1)`. Note `x` and `y` attributes can be numpy arrays. In this case a `Coord` instance could be though as a set of points. For example `Coord([1, 2, 0],[2, -1, 3])` represents the points/vectors `(1, 2), (2, -1) and (0, 3)`.

#### Rotation around the origin

Let's add a method `_rotate_from_origin` to the class `Coord` that outputs the point after rotation. You can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions) an explanation of how to rotate a point.

```py
    def _rotate_from_origin(self, theta):
        return Coord(
            self.x * np.cos(theta) - self.y * np.sin(theta),
            self.x * np.sin(theta) + self.y * np.cos(theta))
```

#### Rotation around a given pivot

It seems that you defined the coordinates `x_ref` and `y_ref`, with the idea of performing the rotation not around the origin but around this reference point. We can simply achieve this using the following method:

```py
    def rotate(self, theta, pivot=None):
        if not pivot:
            pivot = Coord(0, 0)
        return (self - pivot)._rotate_from_origin(theta) + pivot
```

That's it! Now you can use this method for any point or set of points.

#### Example

Let's try on your example (or at least on what I understood of it).

```py
startA = Coord([0, -1], [ 0, -1])  # points that will be rotated with an angle of thetaA
startB = Coord([3,  2], [-1,  0])  # will be rotated with an angle of thetaB
pivot = Coord(1, 1)
thetaA = -np.pi / 4
thetaB = np.pi / 4

## Rotate each set of points with the corresponding angle
rotatedA = startA.rotate(thetaA, pivot=pivot)
rotatedB = startB.rotate(thetaB, pivot=pivot)

## Display the result
plt.plot(pivot.x, pivot.y, 'ko')
plt.plot(startA.x, startA.y, 'o', c='gold')
plt.plot(rotatedA.x, rotatedA.y, 'o', c='gold')
plt.plot(startB.x, startB.y, 'o', c='lightblue')
plt.plot(rotatedB.x, rotatedB.y, 'o', c='royalblue')
```

[image: results]

Note that here `theta` parameter is a single integer. In this case each points will be rotated using the same `theta` value. But several values of thetas can be used to make each point rotate differently. For instance we could have done:

```py
starts = Coord([0, -1, 3, 2], [0, -1, -1, 0])
pivot = Coord(1, 1)
thetas = (np.pi / 4) * np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1])

rotated = starts.rotate(thetas, pivot=pivot)
```

And the same applies to the `pivot` parameter. Basically this is the expected behavior when using functions with numpy.